# mpicc with no warning when compiling

Tags: compilation, mpi

I would like to know what flag to use in order to avoid warning messages that appear when compiling a C/C++ parallel using mpicc. More specifically, I prefer not to have my screen of messages referring to unused variables,e.g.  warning: unused variable

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most (?) MPI compiler wrappers will pass compiler options to the compiler that they wrap.  so you should be able to use the same flag, for `mpicc`, that you would use for your compiler unwrapped.

For a better answer: consult the source of your installation of `mpicc` which is generally implemented (on Linux systems) as a shell script.  Many versions also respond to `-help` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by High Performance Mark, `mpicc` is simply a wrapper around the real compiler toolchain. There is an almost standard option that (almost) all wrappers understand: `-showme`. It shows you what flags exactly get passed on to the compiler, e.g.:

```
$ mpicc -showme
icc <lots of preprocessor flags> -fexceptions -pthread \
    <lots of linker flags> -lmpi -losmcomp -lrdmacm -libverbs -lrt \
    -lnsl -lutil -lpsm_infinipath -lbat -llsf -ldl -lm -lnuma
```

Examine these options, consult your compiler's manual and find out how to suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your compiler , you can add flags to avoid such warning messages, for instance `-w` is the GCC-wide option to disable warning messages.