# Arrays being randomly overwritten in C program. Probably simple solution

Tags: c, arrays, variables

I have 4 functions that run through a text file and store the values to their designated arrays decalred at the beginning of the problem. The issue i'm having is that when I update one of the arrays the others all are never updated or are reset. So for example if I run the getkosDS function it will update the array and print out the value i am looking for. The other arrays will contain zero. However if I comment out the getkosDS function the next array (nipsDS) will update and not be zero!!! I am very confused.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int kosND;
int kosNW;
int kosNZC;
int enronND;
int enronNW;
int enronNZC;
int nipsND;
int nipsNW;
int nipsNZC;
int nytND;
int nytNW;
int nytNZC;
int world_size;
int my_rank;
int kosDS[3430];
int nipsDS[1500];
int enronDS[39861];
int nytDS[300000];

void getKOS(){
    int i;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docword.kos.txt","r");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i == 0){
                kosND = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 1){
                kosNW = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 2){
                kosNZC = atoi(line);
        }
    }
    fclose(MyFile);
}

void getEnron(){
    int i;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docword.enron.txt","r");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i == 0){
                enronND = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 1){
                enronNW = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 2){
                enronNZC = atoi(line);
        }
    }
}

void getNips(){
    int i;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docword.nips.txt","r");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i == 0){
                nipsND = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 1){
                nipsNW = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 2){
                nipsNZC = atoi(line);
        }
    }
    fclose(MyFile);
}

void getNYT(){
    int i;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docword.nytimes.txt","r");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i == 0){
                nytND = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 1){
                nytNW = atoi(line);
        }
        if(i == 2){
                nytNZC = atoi(line);
        }
    }
    fclose(MyFile);
}

void getKosDS(){
    int i;
    int z;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docstart.kos.txt","r");
    for(i = 0; i<3430; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i != 0 && i % 2 == 1){
                kosDS[z] = atoi(line);
                z++;
        }
    }
    fclose(MyFile);
}


int getNipsDS(){
    int i;
    int z;
    FILE *MyFile;
    char line[25];
    MyFile=fopen("/home/mcconnel/BagOfWords/docstart.nips.txt","r");
    for(i = 0; i<1500; i++){
        fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);
        if(i != 0 && i % 2 == 1){
                nipsDS[z] = atoi(line);
                z++;
        }
    }
    fclose(MyFile);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
  // printf("\n%d", world_size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  // printf("\n%d", my_rank);
   if(my_rank == 0){
        getKOS();
        getEnron();
        getNips();
        getNYT();
        getKosDS();
      //  getEnronDS();
      //  getNytDS();
        printf("\ngetting complete\n");
        printf("KOS location %d\n", kosDS[5]);
      //  printf("Enron location %d\n", enronDS[200]);
        printf("Nips location %d\n", nipsDS[500]);
      //  printf("NYT location %d\n", nytDS[10000]);

   }
   else{

        printf("\n%d \n", my_rank);

   }
   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

this is the result

KOS location 4875
Nips location 0

however if I were to comment out getKosDS the result is

KOS location 0
Nips location 28340

Craziness, if you can't tell I'm new to C

Comment: Being new to C is not a crime. Ignoring the warnings your compiler reports is, and problems like this are reported by most compilers. Look at your compiler output and if you find mention, learn from this mistake to improve your programming future.

Comment: That is a lot of variables. Perhaps a rethink on data structures

Comment: My compiler didn't inform me of anything, were running off a unix server so I'm not really using a sophisticated IDE or anything

Comment: Paradoxically, a no-ide compiler's output is much easier to see and understand...

Comment: Nevertheless, you should get warnings for uninitialized vars, no matter whether dumped on a console window or in the build messages pane of an IDE, (where, at least, you can click them with your mouse and have the source pane highlight the error, ready for fixing).

Comment: I wish it did! this is my first time programming in this fashion. We're using putty, do you think there's a better way to go about it?

Comment: Not having an IDE is not a reason to not get warnings - in fact, it makes it less likely to not get them. Using putty is fine (well, it's irrelevant... it's just a means of getting shell access on the machine). When you compile, does your compiler emit no information at all? Perhaps you're redirecting output somewhere?

Comment: Putty I'd not an ide

Comment: I get errors only if it is going to crash the program. When I compile this I get no errors whatsoever

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment: My professor told us to compile using mpicc p3a4.c

Comment: p3a4 being the name of my program obviously

Comment: Well, being a wrapper perhaps it is suppressing some warnings..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733817/mpicc-with-no-warning-when-compiling suggests that mpicc does output warnings (but it also suggests that mpicc is just a front end for some other compiler).

Comment: If i can compile it in a better way please let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately the development environment for DSP and microcontrollers seems to be a few generations behind modern times. That might not be true universally and my experiences in this environment are not too recent so perhaps it's not so common now, but in general I expect sub-par tools for the environment :(

Comment: ugh lol, it's frustrating enough working with a new language let alone a sub-par compiler. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Note: `mipcc` usually is a front end for `gcc`.   when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  I see 3 warnings to be fixed:  1) unused parameter `argc`  2) unused parameter: `argv[]`  3) missing `return int_value;` at end of function: `getNipsDs()`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for good programming practice, only one statement per line and (at max) only one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: for the purposes of debugging (and the features are not actually used) strongly suggest removing all references to the `MPI` functions

Comment: when calling `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  The returned value is a count of the number of successful input/conversion format specifiers in the format string.  Suggest: `if( formatSpecifierCount != fscanf( ... ) ) { // then error occurred, handle error and exit }

Comment: The posted code and question do not indicate the actual contents of each of the files.  But, in the `getKOS()` function, the call to `atoi()` function is always converting the same value.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `fscanf(MyFile, "%s", line);`  1) check the returned value (in this case it should be 1.)   2) the '%s` format specifier has no length limit,  so could easily overrun the `line` buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `fscanf(MyFile, "%*s", sizeof(line)-1, line);

Comment: in the `getKOS()` function there is a `for()` loop that loops 5 times.  However, only the first three loops have any activity,  So why not 3 times rather than 5?

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the posted code.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Some of the 'magic' numbers are: 3430, 1500, 39861, 300000, 25, 5.   Suggest using `#define`s or an `enum` to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in the function: `getNYT()` (and elsewhere)  the series of statements like: `if(i == 0)`  would be more clearly written as a `switch statement`

Comment: the posted code does not set any of the `int kosDS[]`, `int nipsDS[]`, `int enronDS[]`, nor `nytDS[]` array values, so you cannot expect those arrays. to contain anything but 0s  so the calls to `printf()` in the `main()` function give no useful values.

Comment: Since your on unix, the `geany` editor should be available.   Some options need to setup then editing, compiling, linking, running are dirt simple and the editor will have window pane that displays all the error messages and they will be `clickable` to jump direct to the where the compiler spotted the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `getKosDS` the `z` is uninitialized, so by writing to `nipsDS[z]` you are actually writing into a random memory location, invoking an undefined behavior.

Update: 
The same problem is in the `getNipsDS` function.

Comment: ditto in `getNipsDS()`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, my teacher has us working on a unix server and the compiler is anything but helpful. Worked perfectly

Comment: Yep will do still have to wait a minute :P